# Creating a wchar to multibyte char function

Tags: c++

The libc library I'm currently using is missing wctomb() so I'm looking to come up with a replacement implementation. What are some complexities I should beware of? Can I simply grab each byte in the wchar and stick them inside an char array?

Comment: Which multibyte encodings are you interested in supporting?

Comment: Maybe you grab inspiration from an existing implementations of the function: http://www.google.com/codesearch?q=wctomb

Comment: Be careful with grabbing inspiration from open source code if you have to create close source

Comment: @Roger- I'm interested in supporting UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to pick up a copy of [P.J. Plauger's book, "The Standard C Library"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131315099) - it provides a basic implementation of `wctomb()` along with a discussion of wide character support in general.

Answer (score 0):

It depends in what encoding is the `wchar` and what encoding do you expect in `char` array. If they are the same (the encodings), then AFAIK yes, you can do it byte by byte, but beware of endiannes.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily assign each wchar to a char if the wchar is <= 127 so only 7bit are used.
As long as you check this and create an error if it isn't given you are save and can do so.

Thats because the first 7 bit og the unicode character (no matter if 8, 16 or 32 bit) is identical with the first 7 bit of ASCII.

If you really want to write a converter you need to know a lot of character tables and so on.

There is a full featured unicode library call [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) which was inspired by IBM. Its very powerful and big. But it might help if nothing helps.

Answer (score -1):

***If*** you are absolutely sure that your program will only ever handle ASCII data (which is really a terrible thing to assume, but it may be necessary), then you can just take the lower-order byte of each `wchar_t` and stuff it into a `char`. But if you ever have to handle any kind of Unicode data, then you're going to be stuck implementing UTF-8, which is a *massive* undertaking best left to experts.

Comment: UTF-8 encoding is not too hard, if you have characters already in Unicode (ie. in some other encoding of Unicode). (But it is still better to not reinvent the wheel and use some library.)